# ViewPager image gallery inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hello im new android developer and i try to do the next things with no success
i have **Activity**, inside the activity i have **fragment** and inside it i have ** view pager image galley**.

the problem is when i run the app with the activity with the fragment and and gallery inside it the app crash
but when i tried to run the activity with the gallery and the fragment separately they works fine
whats the problem?
here my code:

**Activity**

public class infoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotel_info);

}
```

}

Activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:name="co.checkit.mobile.checkit.Model.gallery_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/imagegalleryfragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentid" />


</LinearLayout>
```

ass you can see i set the fragment inside the activity

**Fragment class**

```
public class Hotelsgallery_fragment extends Fragment {


    ImageAdapter adapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagegalleryfragment, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        return myFragmentView;
    }
}


i set the gallery inside the fragment class
```

**Fragment XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager">



</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting fragment inside xml, put frame layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout_id" />


</LinearLayout>
```

create fragment inside a activity, inflate using frame layout id

```
        YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.frame_layout_id, fragment);

        ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you please to detail more?. by saying to create the fragment inside the activity you mean to  execute the connection between the activity and the fragment in the activity?